# Not able set permission on /etc/grub.conf

Tags: rhel

I have logged in as a root user, but i'm not able to set the permission on /etc/grub.conf.
Here the /etc/grub.conf file is a symbolic link (also symlink or soft link) to /boot/grub/grub.conf file. 
If i give the beolw command to change the permission on /etc/grub.conf, it is not getting affetced to /etc/grub.conf. But this is getting reflected to /boot/grub/grub.conf file.

**chmod 700 /etc/grub.conf**

Please tell the reason for this and the relation between /etc/grub.conf and /boot/grub/grub.conf

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change permissions on a symbolic link. You should change the permsissions to the original file, and the restrictions will apply to the link.

AFAIK, the symlinks have something like 777 permissions precisely because you'd want them to reflect the original file restrictions. (Otherwise, I could create a symlink to, say, `/etc/passwd` and give myself privileges and do weird stuff there).

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the permissions of a symbolic link. Operations on the symbolic link will be on the file that the symbolic points to, so there is no need to be able to change the permissions.